# Using multiple cells to search for data from a different sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets in my workbook. The first is supposed to display data from the second sheet that has a lot of data.

I have put a macro button on the display sheet where if I enter a specific value in the referenced cell and then click the button it displays all the rows in my data sheet that has it's value.

The problem is I can only search for a single value to display but I want to use another two cells to put other values like using conditions, to be specific is date duration.

> cell 1... Name,
>   cell 2... Start Date,
>   cell 3... End Date

Upon clicking the button it should display all the rows in the data sheet that has the values of specific name, a date in the second cell and a date in the third cell.

Here's the code I'm currently using,

```
Sub SearchMultipleValues()
Dim eRow As Long  
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim count As Integer

lastrow = Sheets("DATA").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Sheet2.Range("A5:L1048569").ClearContents

count = 0

Dim p As Long
p = 2

For X = 2 To lastrow

    If Sheets("DATA").Cells(X, 1) = Sheet2.Range("A1") Then

        Sheet1.Cells(p, 1) = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(X, 1)
        Sheet1.Cells(p, 2) = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(X, 2)
        Sheet1.Cells(p, 3) = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(X, 3)
        Sheet1.Cells(p, 4) = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(X, 4)
        Sheet1Cells(p, 5) = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(X, 5)
        Sheet1.Cells(p, 6) = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(X, 6)
        Sheet1.Cells(p, 7) = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(X, 7)
        Sheet1.Cells(p, 8) = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(X, 8)
        Sheet1.Cells(p, 9) = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(X, 9)
        Sheet1.Cells(p, 10) = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(X, 10)
        Sheet1.Cells(p, 11) = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(X, 11)
        Sheet1.Cells(p, 12) = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(X, 12)
        p = p + 1
        count = count + 1

    End If

Next X

MsgBox " The number of item found is " & " " & count

End Sub
```

The cell A1 is where I type the value I want to display in the "Sheet1" that is from the data sheet "Sheet2". Now I want to include cell A2 and A3 as additional values that sticks with the value in cell A1 in the data sheet.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  "*The problem is I can only search for a single value to display but i wanted to use another 2 cells to put another values [...]*", makes me think you want to be more restrictive in your matches; like using `SumIfs` instead of `SumIf`.  But... "*Upon clicking button it will display all the rows in the data sheet that has the values of specific name, a date in the second cell and a date in the third cell*", makes it seem like you only want to include the values in the output.   A `PivotTable` can do both, so not use that instead of VBA?

Answer (score 0):

You can abandon the loop altogether. Try using [`Filter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter) method of the *Range Object*.

```
Dim sh As Worksheet, lastrow As Long, datarange As Range
Set sh = Sheets("DATA") '// set the source sheet //
'// clear destination sheet focusing on columns that will be used //
Sheet2.Range("A5:L" & Sheet2.Rows.Count).ClearContents

With sh
  lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  Set datarange = .Range("A1:L" & lastrow) '// set the source row //
End With
'// filter based on sheet2 A1 value //
datarange.AutoFilter 1, Sheet2.Range("A1").Value2, xlFilterValues
'// copy filtered values
datarange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
'// paste to destination
Sheet2.Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
```

You can have a go at this and if it works, adjust to suit your needs. This is not tested as I have no way of doing it now. Hope this helps though.